# Gosa with openldap giving php error on startup

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am trying to setup GOsa and OpenLDAP on a Centos 7 machine and am encountering some issues.

Mainly when i access the /gosa webpage I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'session' not found in /usr/share/gosa/include/php_setup.inc on line 91
```

Installation steps:

- Addition of http://oss.gonicus.de/pub/gosa/redhat yum repository
- Installation of yum modules (latest version):

  - openldap
  - openldap-clients
  - openldap-servers
  - gosa-schema.noarch
  - gosa-plugin-systems.noarch
  - gosa-plugin-sudo.noarch
  - gosa-plugin-squid.noarch
  - gosa-plugin-samba.noarch
  - gosa-plugin-rolemanagement.noarch
  - gosa-plugin-pureftpd.noarch
  - gosa-plugin-mail.noarch
  - gosa-plugin-log.noarch
  - gosa-plugin-ldapmanager.noarch
  - gosa-plugin-dns.noarch
  - gosa-plugin-dhcp.noarch
  - gosa-plugin-connectivity.noarch
  - gosa-plugin-addressbook.noarch
  - gosa.noarch
- switching expose_php off and magic_quotes_gpc on in php files
- Setting up /etc/openldap/ldap.conf as follows (later)
- copying /usr/share/gosa/plugins/pureftpd/contrib/pureftpd.schema to /etc/openldap/schema/gosa/pureftpd.schema
- copying /usr/share/gosa/plugins/dns/contrib/dnszone.schema to /etc/openldap/schema/gosa/dnszone.schema
- adding gosa_custom.schema to /etc/openldap/schema/gosa_custom.schema (follows later)
- opening up apache access by setting Require all granted in the directory /
- copying /usr/share/openldap-servers/DB_CONFIG.example to /var/lib/ldap/DB_CONFIG
- running /usr/sbin/update-gosa
- starting ldap and apache

ldap.conf (sample data)

```
include         /etc/openldap/schema/corba.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/dyngroup.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/java.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/misc.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/openldap.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/ppolicy.schema

include /etc/openldap/schema/gosa/samba3.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/gosa/pureftpd.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/gosa/gofon.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/gosa/gosystem.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/gosa/goto.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/gosa/gosa-samba3.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/gosa/gofax.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/gosa/goserver.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/gosa/goto-mime.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/gosa/trust.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/gosa/dnszone.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/gosa/gosa_custom.schema

pidfile     /var/run/openldap/slapd.pid
argsfile    /var/run/openldap/slapd.args

database    bdb
suffix      "dc=FogoNaCaixadAgua"
rootdn      "cn=Manager,dc=FogoNaCaixadAgua"

# Senha gerada pelo comando slappasswd -h {SSHA}
rootpw      {SSHA}Nag4FWwXLoGO/WpdpFJUlMVCBYwB94wt

directory   /var/lib/ldap

index entryCSN,entryUUID eq
index uid,mail eq
index gosaMailAlternateAddress,gosaMailForwardingAddress eq
index cn,sn,givenName,ou pres,eq,sub
index objectClass pres,eq
index uidNumber,gidNumber,memberuid eq
index gosaSubtreeACL,gosaObject,gosaUser pres,eq
index sambaSID eq
index sambaPrimaryGroupSID eq
index sambaDomainName eq

cachesize 100000
```

gosa_custom.schema

```
#$Id: authldap.schema,v 1.8 2005/03/20 19:10:30 mrsam Exp $
#
# OID prefix: 1.3.6.1.4.1.25981
#
# Attributes: 1.3.6.1.4.1.25981.1.1
#
# Depends on: gosa.schema and cosine.schema

attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.25981.1.1.1 NAME 'gosaMailHome'
    DESC 'The absolute path to the mail message stor directory in a virtual mail setup.'
        EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 SINGLE-VALUE )

#
# Objects: 1.3.6.1.4.1.25981.1.2
#

objectclass ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.25981.1.2.1 NAME 'gosaVirtualMailAccount' SUP top AUXILIARY
    DESC 'Objectclass to mark Virtual MailAccounts for GOsa (v2.4)'
        MAY ( gosaMailHome ) )
```

Comment: "running /usr/sbin/update-gosa" AFAIK the command should be executed in the gosa dir, for e.g. 'cd /usr/share/gosa && ./update-gosa'

Comment: still getting the same error